# What is an abelian group in a symmetric monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, monoidal-categories

Reading Tom Leinster's book [Higher operads, higher categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049v1) , I found Example 2.1.5 a bit puzzling. It says:

> For instance, let $V$ be a symmetric monoidal category and let $Ab(V)$ be the category of abelian groups in $V$.

I couldn't find a previous reference for what is an abelian group in a symmetric monoidal category. So, what is that?

Comment: Do you know what a group object in a category is?

Comment: I know what a group object in a category with finite products is, if that helps.

Comment: Well then it's the same, but you repace finite products with tensor products

Comment: Note quite : you need diagonal morphisms to define inverses. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that a monoidal category where you can define group object has to be cartesian, I'll see if I can find it again.

Answer (score 4):

I also don't know what an abelian group, or for that matter a group, in a symmetric monoidal category is; as mentioned by Arnaud the problem is that the naive definition requires diagonals to define inverses. Fortunately, for the purposes of the example it suffices to think about commutative monoids, and those have a straightforward definition.

What is true is that in a symmetric monoidal category you can define [Hopf monoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+monoid), which in any cartesian monoidal category gives groups, and which in e.g. $\text{Vect}$ gives Hopf algebras.

Comment: You mention that for the example it suffices to think about commutative monoids. Then, Tom says, "In general $V$ will not have enough colimits to
define a tensor product on $Ab(V)$". I find this a bit puzzling again, wouldn't I obtain a monoidal structure for commutative monoids as the monoidal structure of $V$ is symmetric ([3.1 in Porst](http://www.math.uni-bremen.de/~porst/dvis/CoBiMon_Porst.pdf))?

Comment: @J.Doe There is such a tensor structure, but that's not the one we usually want to consider. Leinster is talking about a tensor product analogous to the one on abelian groups, or commutative monoids, that's left adjoint to the internal hom. Porst's monoidal structure is just the biproduct, in that case. You can characterize the desired fancier tensor product, when $V$ is closed, by lifting the closedness to commutative monoids and asking for its left adjoint, or when there's a free commutative monoid functor, by asking that it be strong monoidal. Otherwise, I don't know how to characterize it.