# Group objects in category of finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory

Let $k$ be a field. What is a group object in the category of finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces?

I believe it must be a commutative algebra of some kind, but I can not convince myself.

Comment: I think all the objects should be group objects, with the various structure morphisms coming from the fact that the object is already an abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually every vector space is a group object in a unique way. Indeed, a group object in $\mathbf{Vect}$ is a vector space $V$ with a group structure; in particular, the unit must be given by a linear map $\{0\}\to V$ (since $\{0\}$ is the terminal object in $\mathbf{Vect}$), so it is just zero, and the multiplication must be a linear map $\mu:V\times V\to V$ such that $\mu(v,0)=x=\mu(0,v)$ for all $v\in V$. But this forces
$$\mu(v,w)=\mu((v,0)+(0,w))=\mu(v,0)+\mu(0,w)=v+w.$$
So the only possible definition of $\mu$ is that it is the addition of $V$. You can check that this is always linear, and of course it is always a group, so every vector space is a group object with its additive group structure.

Note that I have never used the scalar multiplication, so this is true for modules over any ring (including the abelian groups). In fact, this is a special case of the Eckmann-Hilton argument, which states that two binary operations that have identities and are homomorphisms of one another must be equal, associative and commutative. So for example, the group objects in the category of groups or even in monoids are exactly the *abelian* groups (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33571/group-objects-in-category-of-groups?rq=1)).

Comment: Ah, thanks! ...What about cogroup objects, ie. $\mathbf{Grp}(\mathbf{f.d.Vect}_k^{op})$?

Comment: For co-group objects the counit $X\to 0$ would still be $0$, and you would have a comultiplication $\delta:V\to V\oplus V=V\times V$; since the canonical arrows $V+V\to V$ induced by $id_V$ and $0$ are just the projections of the product $V\times V$, the identities defining a comonoid will imply that $\delta(v)=(v,v)$. The inverse will just be defined by taking opposites. So every object is a co-group in a unique way.

Comment: If you really want to find algebras, what you need is the monoids in the *monoidal* category of vector spaces with the tensor product as monoidal product (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category). See also this recent question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564873/what-is-an-abelian-group-in-a-symmetric-monoidal-category